# Proving that a discrete stochastic variable is binomial distributed.

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Given a discrete stochastic variables, with the probability function;
$$
p_{X}\left(x\right)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{4} & \text{if } x = -1 \\
\frac{1}{4} & \text{if } x = 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & \text{if } x = 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
How do I prove that;
$$|X| \sim b\left(1, \frac{3}{4}\right)$$
What I've done so far: Found $P(|X| = 1) = \frac{3}{4}$, and then I've unsuccessfully tried to derive the probability function (above) from the binomial probability function (below);
$$
p\left(x\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
n \\ x
\end{array}\right) \pi^{x} \left(1 - \pi\right)^{n-x}
$$
However without any luck, as $|X| \neq X$.

So my question is somewhat simple; How would I go about proving that a discrete stochastic variable is binomial distributed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already did all of the work. You showed that
$$
p_{\left|\mathbf{X}\right|}\left(x\right)
=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
x
\end{array}\right)\frac{3}{4}^{x}\frac{1}{4}^{1-x}
=
\begin{cases}
\frac{3}{4} & \text{if }x=1\\
\frac{1}{4} & \text{if }x=0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Wouldn't that be $
p_{|X|}\left(x\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\ x
\end{array}\right) \frac{3}{4}^{x} \frac{1}{4}^{1-x}
$? - Also why is the support = {0,1}? - Is it the support is the same as $p_{X}\left(X\right)$, however with $-1$ excluded due to it's undefinedness in factorial?

Comment: Also, how does this prove that $|X|$ is binomial distributed? - Because it is possible to write it to binomial distributed form, while retaining the $P(|X| = 1)$?

Comment: Yes to the correction. As for the support, $p_{\left|\mathbf{X}\right|}\left(x\right)=0$ for anything other
than $x=0$ or $x=1$. We say an r.v. is binomially distributed if its probability mass function at $k$ is given by $\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\k\end{array}\right)p^{k}\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}$ for some $p$ and $n$. You showed this (specifically, with $n=1$ and $p=3/4$).

Comment: I'm still uncertain about why the support is $= {0,1}$?

Comment: The support of a function is defined as the set of points on which the function is nonzero. The function is nonzero only at $x=1$ and $x=0$.

Comment: I get that, however, I'm uncertain about how to find these values? That is how do I determine which $x$ to test for non-zero probability? - Trial and error? - Intuition?